# Install4j create user data directory

Tags: install4j

Install4j has the system variable sys.docsdir that will create a data directory in the proper place.  But I can not find an action to add to the installation that will create an empty directory.  What is the action?  If I need to create custom script, a sample would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installer variable `sys.docsdir` contains the path to the user-specific "Documents" folder on Windows, it does not create a directory.

To install files into a subfolder of the `sys.docsdir` directory, add a new root under Files->Define distribution tree with the name `${installer:sys.docsdir}/myfolder` and add the files below that folder.

To install to a folder that is resolved at runtime, the name of the installation root can contain your own installer variable, like `${installer:myDataDir}`. In that case, you have to define that variable (for example with a "Set a variable" action) before the "Install files" action runs.

Answer (score 1):

You may find your answer here, in the following link:

http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/12/more-installation-options-with.html

Hope it helps you.